# Why can't I enter five characters into the array in the first code, but can when using a getchar() as shown in the second code?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, getchar

I can't enter all the 5 characters into the array if I use the first code. But if I use the second code it works. Why?

### Code:1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i,n;
char a[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d::",i+1);
    scanf("%c",&a[i]); //I can input only 1,3,5 values.
}
printf("Enter:\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
printf("%c",a[i]);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

### Code:2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i,n;
char a[5];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    printf("%d::",i+1);
    scanf("%c",&a[i]);
    getchar();
}
printf("Enter:\n");
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
printf("%c",a[i]);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when you enter a character, you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. `scanf` will consume the character and then leaves the newline character(`\n`) in the standard input stream(`stdin`). When `scanf` with a `%c` is called the next time, it sees the newline character persisting in the `stdin` and directly consumes it, and thus, does not wait for further input.

In the second code, the `getchar()` consumes the `\n` character left over by the previous call to `scanf` in each iteration. This is why the second code works as expected.